# Glimpse client side tool not appearing after setup on ASP.NET MVC 3 Site

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, glimpse

So I installed glimpse using NuGet, confirmed that the web.config got updated, entered "MySite/glimplse.axd" turned the service on and I do not see the client side tool. I have used glimpse on other sites and its usually smooth but the current application is several orders of magnitude more complex, It has several HttpModules and is currently set up on my local IIS7 installation (not running in Cassini), is there anything that could be interfering with Glimplse that I should be aware of ?

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem after updating Glimpse this morning (v1.3.0). Here's what I did to solve this.

Turn on tracing for Glimpse

```
<glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd">
    <logging level="Trace" />
</glimpse>
```

Turn on tracking for Asp.net

```
<system.web>
  ...
  <trace enabled="true" pageOutput="true" requestLimit="40" localOnly="true"/> ...
```

The tracing output gave me a hint what had happen.

In my case, request to Glimpse.axd got a 404 response due to the Forms authentication.

p/s: Glimpse update (via nuget) will modify the Web.Config file, and I always have to manually undo those changes (my Web.config have several `<location path=>` that wrap `system.web` and `system.webServer` and the updates seem to ignore them).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get a bit more information about why Glimpse is not showing up by enabling logging in your web.config.

```
<glimpse enabled="true" loggingEnabled="true">
```

If the log file doesn't seem to spell it out for you, post it here for help reviewing.

Comment: oh nice, Playing with it now, will post results. Thank you.

Comment: so the log is not quite helpfull, I get these warnings: 
get_Binders method of System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker type is not proxyable.
set_Binders method of System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker type is not proxyable.
GetType method of System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker type is not proxyable.
MemberwiseClone method of System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker type is not proxyable.

Comment: Well that is good news because it means Glimpse is running. There should be other lines in the file that tell you why Glimpse may not to embedding itself to a given request.